# ¿Cómo obtener los elementos que no se repiten en un array?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente array con n objetos: (Ejemplo)

```
const array = [
  {
    institucion: "LUS",
    servicio: "listCon",
  }
];
```

Necesito sacar solo los objetos que no se repiten de ese array. Pero en su lugar he logrado sacar solo los que se repiten, con esta función:

```
const busqueda = array.reduce((acc, persona) => {

  const clave = JSON.stringify(persona);
  acc[clave] = ++acc[clave] || 0;
  return acc;
}, {});


const duplicados = array.filter( (persona) => {
    return busqueda[JSON.stringify(persona)];
});

console.log(duplicados);
```

Con esto solo logro sacar los que se repiten, y necesito sacar los que no se repiten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi que tenias la respuesta , al momento  que decis " logro sacar los que se repiten" , esto lo logras como bien hiciste con filter , tenes que mirar la salida de busqueda ,te agrego unos objetos para el ejemplo

### salida de busqueda

```
console.log(busqueda)
/*{
  '{"institucion":"LUS","servicio":"listCon"}': 2,
  '{"institucion":"LAB","servicio":"listCon"}': 0,
  '{"institucion":"azs","servicio":"listCas"}': 0 
}*/
```

### Duplicados

se entiendo que filter devuelve los que cumplen con la condicion y 0 va a evaluar como [false](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Boolean) , para convertirlo a true y que se filtre usas la negacion `!`

```
const duplicados = array.filter((persona) => 
!busqueda[JSON.stringify(persona)])
```

```js
let array = [
    {
        institucion: 'LUS',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'LUS',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'LAB',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'LUS',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'azs',
        servicio: 'listCas',
    },
]

const busqueda = array.reduce((acc, persona) => {
    const clave = JSON.stringify(persona)
    acc[clave] = ++acc[clave] || 0
    return acc
}, {})

 

const duplicados = array.filter((persona) => 
!busqueda[JSON.stringify(persona)])

console.log(duplicados)
```

busqueda[JSON.stringify(persona)])

Comment: Excelente, eso me funciono como queria :)

Answer (score 0):

No especificas si validas el objeto entero o solo una propiedad. En caso de que fuera solo una propiedad podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const array = [
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LAB',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
];

const unicos = [];
const x = array.reduce((acc, valor) => {
  if (!unicos.includes(valor.institucion)) {
    unicos.push(valor.institucion);
    acc.push(valor);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```

**Edit:** Haciendo uso de ES6+

O una versión más corta podría ser con filter.

```javascript
array.filter(
  (v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => t.institucion === v.institucion) === i
);
```

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, pero necesito eliminar los objetos repetidos, y necesesito obtener solo los que no se repiten, con tu ejemplo solo necesitaria obtener { institucion: 'LAB', servicio: 'listCon' } porque es el unico que no se repite

Answer (score 0):

Puede que mi respuesta no sea la mas optimizada pero si funciona como creo quieres que lo haga

```js
const array = [
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LAB',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
];

const value = array.reduce((acc, current, index, array) => {
    if(array.filter(row => row.institucion === current.institucion).length > 1){
        return acc;
    }
    else { return [...acc, current];}
},[])

console.log(value)
```

Lo que hago principalmente es recorrer los array y por cada valor pregunto si existe mas de una vez en el mismo array, si esta mas de una vez no lo agrego al array final

Comment: De la manera en que lo planteas funciona con el array de ejemplo, pero a la hora de agregar mas objetos al array, solo me devuelve 1 que no se repite, y yo necesito todos :(

Comment: Agregue mas objetos al array de ejemplos y si funciono, podrías proporcionar tu ejemplos en el caso de que no te haya funcionado?

Answer (score 0):

otra forma de hacerlo sería primero almacenar cuantas veces se repiten la institución en el array para luego hacer un filtro y mostrar solo los que se hayan encontrado una vez

```js
const array = [
    {
        institucion: 'LUS',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'LAB',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
    {
        institucion: 'LUS',
        servicio: 'listCon',
    },
];

const contInstitution = array.reduce((acc, current, index) => {

    let institution = current.institucion

    acc[institution] = acc[institution] === undefined ? 1 : acc[institution] +=1

    return acc

}, [])

const arrayFinal = array.filter(({institucion}) => contInstitution[institucion] == 1)

console.log(arrayFinal)
```

con esto se estaría recorriendo el array dos veces, no se me ocurrió nada para que solo se hiciera un recorrido, si alguien publica una solución de un solo recorrido seria mas recomendable que uses ese

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes usar es la funcion [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) de javascript, este genera un arreglo con valores unicos e irrepetibles, lo malo es cuando son objetos, estos son diferentes tipos de datos aun cuando sean identicos, pero puedes parsearlo al momento de guardarlos en Set.
Este es un ejemplo:

```
const array = [
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LAB',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
  {
    institucion: 'LUS',
    servicio: 'listCon',
  },
];

let nuevo = new Set();
array.forEach((item)=>{
  nuevo.add(JSON.stringify(item));
});
```